# No such file or directory when trying to create a file with nano

Tags: command-line, nano

I am trying to create a new file:

```
nano/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
```

When upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, but I'm getting the error:

```
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `nano/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy` literally? Try it with a space after the command name: `nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy`. You’ll need root permissions for that.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like there is a typo in your question because there would normally be a blank space between `nano` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/...` To create a new file named 02proxy in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory (which normally already exists) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
```

To open the 02proxy file for editing in nano text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
```

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

this behavior happen if the target directory doesn't exist. you have therefore to create the parent directory

```
mkdir my_dir
```

then use nano.

```
nano my_file
```

CTRL x=>y

Comment: Creating a directory won't help if you don't put a space between the _command_ (`nano`) and the _file_ it applies to (`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy`). The OP basically issued `nanomy_file` instead of `nano my_file`.